# Multithreading - Make thread start executing run() only after all threads have been started

Tags: java

I am currently learning multithreading in Java and trying to write my first Multithreading game. Threads in my game are players which uses functions from class `Game` which at the same time uses functions from class `Cars` to change the the data in `Cars`. I've noticed that my threads don't start at the same time; Thread-1 has already changed the data whereas Thread-2 hasn't started yet.

```
Go player0
Go player1
Go player2
196 // player0 changed data in Cars
Go player3
196 // player1 changed data in Cars
```

I create threads in method inside `Game` class

```
public void createPlayers() throws Exception{
            for(int i = 0; i < num; ++i){
                Player p = new  Player(i);
                p.start();
                System.out.println("Go "+p.name);
            }
        }
```

At first I thought it was a problem with synchronisation as my threads use `synchronised` method from `Game` class which uses `synchronised` methods from class `Cars`.

```
//function from Game
`public synchronized void changeTire(){
                int rnd = new Random().nextInt(hand.length());
                int rnd2 = new Random().nextInt(tires.length);
                discard(hand.get(rnd),lasttire); // function from Car
                this.lastBag = rnd2;


            }
```

But removing-changing synchronised methods didn't solve the problem. Can I somehow fix it in run() method?

class Players:

```
public class Player extends Thread {
    volatile int n;
    String name;
    PrintWriter b;
    int lasttire;
    AtomicIntegerArray hand;

    public Player(int a) throws IOException {
        n = a;
        this.name = "player"+n;
        Thread.currentThread().setName(this.name);
        String file = "player"+n+"_output.txt";
        b = new PrintWriter(file,"UTF-8");
    }
    public void run(){
        if (gameOn) {
            takeHand();
            while (sum() != 100 && !isInterrupted()) {
                changeTire();
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                } catch (InterruptedException b) {
                    System.out.println("We have a winner!");
                }
            }
            System.out.println("to");
            StopGame();

        }else{
            b.close();
        }


    }
```

Comment: Use https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html to wait until all players are ready in your run() method

Comment: Take a closer look at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html this will help you to sychronize your code. Exaxtly whar @falcon mentioned. (The link was shortened)

Answer (score 0):

Try to check alive threat or not, `if(thread.isAlive()){}`